# Converting Java code to work on android troubles?

Tags: java, android, input

i'm having trouble making some java code i have work with android studio, the main problems i'm having is turning keyboard inputs into swipes and presses from the user, this is my current code for keyboard inputs:

```
class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if (!isStarted || curPiece.getShape() == foodShapes.NoShape) {
                return;
            }

            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keycode == 'p' || keycode == 'P') {
                pause();
                return;
            }

            if (isPaused)
                return;

            switch (keycode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    tryMove(curPiece, curX - 1, curY);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    tryMove(curPiece, curX + 1, curY);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    tryMove(curPiece.rotateRight(), curX, curY);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    tryMove(curPiece.rotateLeft(), curX, curY);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    dropDown();
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    oneLineDown();
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    oneLineDown();
                    break;
            }
```

any help would be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: The previous response amuses me, despite how inaccurate it is.. "_Android Code_" is an incorrect addressing..  Android is a Java overlay (or interface) laid down on top of a Linux kernel..  Android supports most (if not all) of the languages supported on your average Linux or Windows system..  The primary language used by Android is, in fact, Java..

Comment: A man should not be asked to solve a problem without being told about it. Valar dohaeris...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html) page is available within the android documentation and tutorials....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
// This example shows an Activity, but you would use the same approach if
// you were subclassing a View.
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;      
        default : 
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }      
}
```

I would suggest, however, that you use [Google](http://google.com/) in the future, before seeking assistance on stack overflow.  The attached link was located via Google on the first page of results for "[android - detect input gestures within your app](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20-%20detect%20input%20gestures%20within%20your%20app)".  In addition, I believe that I have come across a question that was directly related to this and it was answered in full.

Please remember; Stack Overflow is not here so that you can be lazy - its here so that you can seek assistance when it is *actually* **required**..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @axierjhtjz Click the first link...  Take a look around the sub-documents of that link.  This does, in fact, answer his question. Edit; To appease you, I've attached a document in this comment, it is one of the links within the referenced page - said document outlines how to do exactly what he's asking; http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: I think it´s an answer to the topic asked but the way and tone of the answer places it on the comment side. If you want edit your answer and add just the response, then if you want, notify the user that he/she should search on Google first on a comment. Keep the answers clear.

Comment: There.  I enabled his complete lack of ethic and entirety of laziness, to better appease yourself.  As-is, this question shouldn't even have been asked as he is showing no examples of any attempts, nor is he giving any indication that he has tried locating any related documents.

Comment: yes, your're right but the one that appeared on the queue was your answer. Hope someone sees the question. Anyway, thanks a lot for the effort mate, really :thumbsup:.